# Axios POST not triggering Laravel Controller

Tags: laravel, axios, vuejs3

I've a Vue js Code which uploading a file to Laravel backend.
the problem that I'm facing is that on my local machine [xampp server] everything works like charm,

but when I upload my project to my online server AXIOS POST not triggering my Laravel controller without any error that shows! in fact the response is getting OK to!!

I'm confused what's going on wrong!

```
 const importData = async fileName=> {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },

    }

  
    let data = new FormData()
 
    data.append('file', fileName)
  
    console.log(fileName)
 
    
    axios.post('/api/importData/', data, config) 
      .then(response => {
        
        router.push({ name: 'prs' })
        swal({
          toast: true,
          position: 'top-end',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 3000,
          timerProgressBar: true,
          icon: "success",
          title: "[ PR ] has been [IMPORTED] successfully  ",
        })
      })

      .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        swal({
          toast: true,
          position: 'top-end',
          showConfirmButton: false,
          timer: 3000,
          timerProgressBar: true,
          icon: "error",
          title: err,
        })
      })
 
  }
```

controller

```
    function importData(Request $request){
       
        $this->validate($request, [
            'file' => 'required|file|mimes:xls,xlsx'
        ]);
        $the_file = $request->file('file');

       
        try{

            ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

            $the_file = $request->file('file');

            $reader = ReaderEntityFactory::createXLSXReader();
            $reader ->open($the_file);

               $data = array();
            foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
                foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
                    // do stuff with the row
                    $cells = $row->getCells();
                             $data[] = [
                    'pr_number' =>$cells[0],
                    'state' =>0,
                    'user_id' =>auth()->id(),
                    'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                    
                ];
                }
            }

            $reader->close();
            $limit = 65000; // Mysql placeholder limit ...

            // foreach (array_chunk($data,1000) as $t)
            // {
            //      DB::table('table_name')->insert($t);
            // }

                foreach (array_chunk($data,1000) as $chunk) {

                  //  DB::table('categories')->insert($chunk);
                  Prs::insert($chunk);
                }


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $error_code = $e->errorInfo[1];
            return back()->withErrors('حدث خطأ أثناء عملية التحميل!');
        }
        return back()->withSuccess('تم تحميل البيانات بنجاح.');
    }
```

Comment: If you check the response from the network request, what does it show?

Comment: the only difference is that local machine gives a 302 response while on server gives 303 , is this normal?

Comment: 303 is definitely not a usual HTTP status, or at least one I've seen. 303 is ["SeeOther"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303)

Comment: the frontend code is only half of the equation to the problem.  it might help to show the code for the endpoint, controller, related configuration, etc.

Comment: i've added the controller part

Comment: Do not add `[SOLVED]` to your question. I've rolled back your edit. Since this was simply a typo, better to simply delete your question.